# Ruby on Rails Application Not Deploying

Tags: ruby-on-rails, ruby, puma

I'm trying to deploy a Ruby on Rails application using a preconfigured image provided by Digital Ocean for RoR applications. However, I'm getting an error as shown below:

```
Puma caught this error: uninitialized constant ActionText::Engine::ApplicationController (NameError)
/home/rails/.rvm/gems/ruby-2.6.5/gems/actiontext-6.0.2.1/lib/action_text/engine.rb:43:in `block (2 levels) in <class:Engine>'
/home/rails/.rvm/gems/ruby-2.6.5/gems/activesupport-6.0.2.1/lib/active_support/callbacks.rb:429:in `instance_exec'
/home/rails/.rvm/gems/ruby-2.6.5/gems/activesupport-6.0.2.1/lib/active_support/callbacks.rb:429:in `block in make_lambda'
/home/rails/.rvm/gems/ruby-2.6.5/gems/activesupport-6.0.2.1/lib/active_support/callbacks.rb:201:in `block (2 levels) in halting'
/home/rails/.rvm/gems/ruby-2.6.5/gems/activesupport-6.0.2.1/lib/active_support/callbacks.rb:607:in `block (2 levels) in default_terminator'
/home/rails/.rvm/gems/ruby-2.6.5/gems/activesupport-6.0.2.1/lib/active_support/callbacks.rb:606:in `catch'
/home/rails/.rvm/gems/ruby-2.6.5/gems/activesupport-6.0.2.1/lib/active_support/callbacks.rb:606:in `block in default_terminator'
/home/rails/.rvm/gems/ruby-2.6.5/gems/activesupport-6.0.2.1/lib/active_support/callbacks.rb:202:in `block in halting'
/home/rails/.rvm/gems/ruby-2.6.5/gems/activesupport-6.0.2.1/lib/active_support/callbacks.rb:514:in `block in invoke_before'
/home/rails/.rvm/gems/ruby-2.6.5/gems/activesupport-6.0.2.1/lib/active_support/callbacks.rb:514:in `each'
/home/rails/.rvm/gems/ruby-2.6.5/gems/activesupport-6.0.2.1/lib/active_support/callbacks.rb:514:in `invoke_before'
/home/rails/.rvm/gems/ruby-2.6.5/gems/activesupport-6.0.2.1/lib/active_support/callbacks.rb:134:in `run_callbacks'
/home/rails/.rvm/gems/ruby-2.6.5/gems/activesupport-6.0.2.1/lib/active_support/execution_wrapper.rb:119:in `complete!'
/home/rails/.rvm/gems/ruby-2.6.5/gems/activesupport-6.0.2.1/lib/active_support/execution_wrapper.rb:76:in `ensure in block in run!'
/home/rails/.rvm/gems/ruby-2.6.5/gems/activesupport-6.0.2.1/lib/active_support/execution_wrapper.rb:76:in `block in run!'
/home/rails/.rvm/gems/ruby-2.6.5/gems/activesupport-6.0.2.1/lib/active_support/execution_wrapper.rb:70:in `tap'
/home/rails/.rvm/gems/ruby-2.6.5/gems/activesupport-6.0.2.1/lib/active_support/execution_wrapper.rb:70:in `run!'
/home/rails/.rvm/gems/ruby-2.6.5/gems/actionpack-6.0.2.1/lib/action_dispatch/middleware/executor.rb:12:in `call'
/home/rails/.rvm/gems/ruby-2.6.5/gems/actionpack-6.0.2.1/lib/action_dispatch/middleware/static.rb:126:in `call'
/home/rails/.rvm/gems/ruby-2.6.5/gems/rack-2.2.2/lib/rack/sendfile.rb:110:in `call'
/home/rails/.rvm/gems/ruby-2.6.5/gems/actionpack-6.0.2.1/lib/action_dispatch/middleware/host_authorization.rb:83:in `call'
/home/rails/.rvm/gems/ruby-2.6.5/gems/webpacker-4.2.2/lib/webpacker/dev_server_proxy.rb:23:in `perform_request'
/home/rails/.rvm/gems/ruby-2.6.5/gems/rack-proxy-0.6.5/lib/rack/proxy.rb:57:in `call'
/home/rails/.rvm/gems/ruby-2.6.5/gems/railties-6.0.2.1/lib/rails/engine.rb:526:in `call'
/home/rails/.rvm/gems/ruby-2.6.5/gems/puma-4.3.3/lib/puma/configuration.rb:228:in `call'
/home/rails/.rvm/gems/ruby-2.6.5/gems/puma-4.3.3/lib/puma/server.rb:682:in `handle_request'
/home/rails/.rvm/gems/ruby-2.6.5/gems/puma-4.3.3/lib/puma/server.rb:472:in `process_client'
/home/rails/.rvm/gems/ruby-2.6.5/gems/puma-4.3.3/lib/puma/server.rb:328:in `block in run'
```

According to what I've read, the solution is to make sure that the `application_controller.rb` file exists. However, it does exist.

Comment: Can you check your `bootsnap` version? from rails version 6.0 or higher Rails required bootsnap 1.4.2

Comment: It's not installed. I tried installing it then I got this error: `ERROR:  Error installing bootsnap: ERROR: Failed to build gem native extension`.

Comment: How  do you deploy your application? With capistrano?

Comment: Yes. However, when I try to do a `bundle install`, I get the error here: https://pastebin.com/L4mrTe4d.

Comment: The error mention about json gem (dependence gem) can not installed.
```
An error occurred while installing json (1.8.3), and Bundler cannot continue.
Make sure that `gem install json -v '1.8.3'` succeeds before bundling.
```
did you install the gem? `gem install json -v '1.8.3'`

Comment: +Quân Hoàng Yes. Same error for bootsnap.